# IOS application - reopen application from background mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to reopen my application from background mode ?

Comment: There is one and only one. User opens it manually.

Comment: @Till, why dont you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @vikingosegundo cause I found this question too trivial to give a full blown answer. Answers that do not reference specifications or exploit the details are from my point of view hardly worth it, hence a simple comment.

Comment: @Till and also because it's incorrect.

Comment: @H2CO3 correct - I was assuming we were talking about approved solutions, my bad.

Comment: @Till no problem, of course it's a little detail only, but who knows, maybe OP considers JB solutions also.

Comment: @H2CO3 entirely right and I actually asked the OP to specify that in his latest question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to open an app automatically. However, you can use [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) to let user know about some event related to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's actually **possible** but only on jailbroken devices. Use the following function from the SpringBoardServices framework:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.mycompany.bundleid"), NO);
```

On non-jailbroken devices, it's not really possible.